# Java BigInteger factorization: division and multiplication differ

Tags: java, biginteger, bigint, factorization

I'm writing a code to factorize a big number (more than 30 digit) in Java.

The number (n) is this: `8705702225074732811211966512111`

The code seems to work and the results are:

- `7`
- `2777`
- `14742873817`

By logic the last item should be obtainable by doing `(n/(fact1 * fact2 * fact3))` and it results:

- `30377199961175839`

I was very happy with this, but then decided to take a little test: I multiplied all the factor expecting to find n... But I didn't!

Here is my check code:

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("8705702225074732811211966512111");

BigInteger temp1 = new BigInteger("7");
BigInteger temp2 = new BigInteger("2777");
BigInteger temp3 = new BigInteger("14742873817");
BigInteger temp4 = n.divide(temp1).divide(temp2).divide(temp3);

System.out.println(n.mod(temp1));
System.out.println(n.mod(temp2));
System.out.println(n.mod(temp3));
System.out.println(n.mod(temp4));

System.out.println(n.divide(temp1).divide(temp2).divide(temp3).divide(temp4));
System.out.println(temp1.multiply(temp2).multiply(temp3).multiply(temp4));

System.out.println(n);
```

As you can see I simply define the number n and the factors (the last one is defined as n/(fact1 * fact2 * fact3) then check that n/eachfactor gives remainder 0.

Then I check that ((((N / (fact1)) / fact2) / fact3) / fact4) = 1

Lastly I check that fact1 * fact2 * fact3 * fact4 = n

The problems are:

1. n mod temp4 is not 0, but 245645763538854
2. fact1 * fact2 * fact3 * fact4 is different from n
3. but ((((N / fact1) / fact2) / fact3) / fact4) = 1

Here is the exact output:

```
0
0
0
245645763538854
1
8705702225074732565566202973257
8705702225074732811211966512111
```

This has no sense... How can the fourth factor be wrong and right at the same time?

Comment: Your third factor `14742873817` is not prime; it's `7 * 2106124831`.

Comment: I've noticed it right now!
Thank you anyway!

Comment: Remember that `BigInteger.divide` _rounds down._  That can result in `((((N / (fact1)) / fact2) / fact3) / fact4) = 1` without all of the factors actually dividing `N`.

Comment: How can I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(temp3.mod(temp1));
```

The above code gives 0, which means temp3 is not prime. temp4 is not a factor.

Comment: Thank you, I realized my mistake

Comment: Yes and no ;)
this is not a question from project euler, but from a quiz a friend asked me to solve (so no)
But i like to solve those problems and sometimes use BigIntegers (so: yes)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to report :

8705702225074732811211966512111/(7*2777*14742873817) = 
30377199961175839.8571428571

Where it should be a whole number.

So, your factorisation is wrong ...  oops  ..

Try bc under linux, for windows : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm.

It can deal with these kind of numbers

Comment: That will be really useful in the future! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[this page](http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php?number=8705702225074732811211966512111) says the actual factorization of your BigInteger is **7*2777*2106124831*212640399728230879**

Comment: This is also pretty useful!

Comment: Not enough reputation, sorry